# User created with useradd instead of adduser loads a wrong Prompt

Tags: linux, debian, bash, bashrc, xterm

I've designed my bash prompt like this `\u@\h>`

When i now create the User `example` with adduser, my prompt looks like `example@host>`
But when i create a User with useradd, my prompt looks like `\u@\h>`

PS1: `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;36m\]\h \[\033[01;33m\]\w \[\033[01;35m\]\$ \[\033[00m\]`

PS2: `>`

PS3: empty

PS4: `+`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: can you put the values for $PS1 $PS2 $PS3 and $PS4 in your question?  Put 4 spaces in front to display them unformatted.

Comment: It sounds like `adduser` is giving the user a different shell compared to `useradd`, or some pre-configuration from `/etc/skel` - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121072

Comment: Yes, i found it. The user which was created with `useradd` has the `/bin/sh` shell by default instead of `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useradd` creates users with the `/bin/sh` shell by default. If you want a different shell for the user, you just have to add the -s option like `useradd -m -s /bin/bash {username}` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
The attributes you have customized are inherited by .bash_profile and/or .bashrc in each users home directory so unless you modify the versions in /etc/skel the changes will only be good for the current user.
**In response to your question:**
My guess is that you simply do not have a home directory as unless you run useradd with the -m option it will not create the home directory (/home/user).

Comment: I always executed the command with the -m option. So the homfolder can't be the problem.